# MDM Enrollment Service: Certificates in provisioning XML

Tags: windows-phone-8, mdm

I am implementing an MDM solution for windows phone 8. I am refering to the [Enterprise Device Management Protocol](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36831) and have a question reqarding certificates during the enrollment phase. The document says that the response should contain:

> the client certificate, the enterprise root CA certificate, and any intermediate CA certificate.

In the sample provisioning XML is shows:

```
<characteristic type="CertificateStore">
    <characteristic type="Root">
        <characteristic type="System">
            <characteristic type="031336C933CC7E228B88880D78824FB2909A0A2F">
                <parm name="EncodedCertificate" value="B64 encoded cert insert here" />
            </characteristic>
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="My" >
    <!-- "My" and “User” are case-sensitive -->
        <characteristic type="User">
            <characteristic type="F9A4F20FC50D990FDD0E3DB9AFCBF401818D5462">
                <parm name="EncodedCertificate" value="B64EncodedCertInsertedHere" />
            </characteristic>
            <characteristic type="PrivateKeyContainer"/>
            <!-- This tag must be present for XML syntax correctness. -->
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</characteristic>
```

I sign my client certificate using an intermediate certificate, that is signed by a Thawte certificate.

```
|Thawte Premium Server CA Certificate
|  - Intermediate Certificate
|    - Signed Client Certificate
```

What certificates do i need to provide in this XML and how would i do it?

Comment: same query have you implemeted it successfully? help me if you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install both the certificates on your device so that it can authenticate your server SSL certificate during handshake.

There are some CA certificates pre installed on Windows Phone 8 device. It may be possible that the root certicate is already installed so in that case you will be able to get away with installing just the intermediate certificate.

Check here the list of pre installed CA certificates

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14217.windows-and-windows-phone-8-ssl-root-certificate-program-april-2012-e-g.aspx

Note : the Coulomb of thumbprint is not visible so just copy the table and paste in to excel to see the more information